# Flutter Keyboard with Math Operators

Tags: flutter

How do I get a keyboard with Mathematical operators in Flutter? Something like this screenshot from Venmo? I’m not seeing a `keyboardType` or dart package that seems to do the trick.

Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you have a look at the [math_keyboard](https://pub.dev/packages/math_keyboard) package?

It seems to be doing exactly what you want.